# What are the digital versions of "clock/punch in" and "clock/punch out"?

Tags: phrase-requests, phrasal-verbs

I looked up the phrasal verbs *clock in*, *clock out*, *punch in* and *punch out* in various British advanced learner's dictionaries and they seem to imply that these verbs concern the analog way of recording your arrivals at and departures from work, as in physically punching holes in a card. The modern digitized ways don't really entail punching holes, but biometrics or location tracking.

So what are the digital versions of those verbs?

Also, the companies I've worked for (two self-designated "English-language" schools) insist on using *check in* and *check out*, but I'm pretty sure you only check in to/out of hotels or airports, or check in your baggage. Could *check in/out* be viable options?

Comment: "clock in" and "clock out" are still widely used. Just as people often talk about dialing a phone number, hanging up a phone, or taping a show.

Comment: Have you checked dictionaries for "check in/out"? [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/check%20in) seems to answer your question.

Comment: There are probably millions of people still working from home post-Covid, for whom clocking on/off at work is now ***logging*** on/off.

Comment: @StuartF I looked up *check out* on Merriam-Webster and it didn't seem to, pardon the pun, check out. As for *check in* in the sense of "to report one's presence or arrival", it seems like it's the "check in to a hotel/airport/convention" rather than "check in to **work**" kind of situation.

Comment: At my work I "sign in" and "sign out" by scanning a card.

Comment: We dial a phone number on phones without dials: Words become moribund as science and technology advances rapidly. Clocking in/out is no longer associated with a clock but with the action of registering one's arrival.

Comment: @Vun-HughVaw I see no reason why check in/out cannot also apply to work. It is a very similar situation to the other examples, reporting / registering your arrival and departure. You can't expect any dictionary to list every possibility.

Comment: @PeterJennings "You can't expect any dictionary to list every possibility" I need something authoritative to rely on, not just speculation from Internet users. If there are contradictions between sources, I'll take the one with better authority and visibility. *check in* is overwhelmingly listed with the "arrive for an accommodation service" sense by Oxford, Cambridge, Longman, Macmillan, Merriam-Webster dictionaries, but so far none has listed the "arrive at work" sense. The dictionaries are pretty explicit in mentioning "airport/hotel," not just any type of place.

Comment: log in, log out, log off, sign in, sign off, sign out, etc.

Comment: I don't see why "clock in" doesn't apply to modern methods just because there isn't a physical, analogue clock and rack of time cards. However you register your arrival there is still a clock involved even if it's the clock built into a computer

Answer (score 2):

Yes, *check in* and *check out* can be used to mean *clock in* and *clock out* at t'mill (other workplaces are available).

OED provides, under the headword *check*, way down at sense 16e

> ***e. to check in*** **or** ***out***: to record the incoming or outgoing of (guests,
> employees, books, etc.). Also intransitive, to record one's arrival at
> or departure from a hotel, factory, etc. (frequently ***to check into*** **or** ***out of***); to arrive or depart. Originally *U.S.*

and the earliest citation of this usage is from 1918.

Comment: They're the same as they used to be before computers, but now you can say _with/on the computer_ afterward if you want to. Verbs don't get digital versions. They just get more metaphorical extensions, like "dialling 911" when there's no dial.

Answer (score 1):

The expressions *sign in/out* and *clock on/off* are often used in my experience. From the comments, *clock in/out* also appears to be common. While these expressions derive from physical actions they have become generalised to include electronic registration.

Another answer has noted that *Check in/out* can be used. In my experience this is not commonly used for electronic registration of employee arrivals/departures. "Check in before you leave" is common, and means "check with an appropriate person to make sure they know you are leaving".

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, thanks for that. Noted and corrected.